# Uniqueness of solution for the ODE $y' = 1 + y^{2/3}$, $y(0) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem 8.3 i) from "An Introduction to Ordinary Differential Equations", Agarwal and Regan asks for the existence and uniqueness of the initial value problem  $y' = 1 + y^{2/3}, y(0) = 0$. Applying the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, one gets $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \dfrac{2}{3}\,y^{-1/3},$$ which is obviously not continuous at $y = 0;$ and thus there must be infinite solutions for the above IVP. However, the solution states that there is a unique solution $3\left(y^{1/3} - \tan^{-1}\left(y^{1/3}\right)\right) = x$, and it seems to check out - I cannot find a trivial solution, or any other solution.
So in cases where one cannot apply the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, how does one prove that there exists a unique solution for the IVP?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the theorem, but I Just googled it on wiki and it doesn't seem to be a necessary and sufficient criteria,  just a sufficient one, so failing to have the requirements doesn't seem to make it fail to have a unique solution.

Comment: That is true, and my question was when it doesn't satisfy those conditions, how does one proceed with proving uniqueness of solution.

Comment: Well,  some wiki-diving and googling found the following as actual necessary and sufficient criteria, but I have no idea how to apply it...been too long since I've done math at this level.  http://ams.org/journals/proc/1967-018-04/S0002-9939-1967-0212240-6/S0002-9939-1967-0212240-6.pdf

Comment: Thanks Alan, it seems to be a useful characterization, but it might not be possible to work out the same procedure for a more complex example.

Comment: Good luck, hopefully someone more familiar with nonlinear ODEs shows up

Comment: The idea is that only $y=0$ creates the non-Lipschitz behavior and you cannot stay there for any period of time because $y' \geq 1$ all the time. This wouldn't happen if the $1$ weren't there.

Comment: Ian, it seems to make sense intuitively, but can it be formalised?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is given by
$$
\int_0^y\frac{ds}{1+s^{2/3}}=x.
$$
Note that the integral on the left is a regular well defined Riemann integral, which proves that the solution exists (it is given above) and unique (since this expression
can be obtained from the original equation by equivalent rearrangements).

Comment: Now to finish it ... Suppose $y$ and $z$ both satisfy this (integral) equation, that is $\int_0^y\,(1 + s^{2/3})^{-1}\, ds = \int_0^z\,(1 + s^{2/3})^{-1}\, ds = x$. Subtracting, $\int_z^y \,(1 + s^{2/3})^{-1}\, ds = 0$. The integrand is positive and continuous, so $y = z$.

Comment: @Aruralreader This is absolutely unnecessary. Integral on the left has no issues (the issues appear, which imply non-uniqueness, when this integral is improper).

Comment: You didn’t show a $y$ satisfying it is unique.